# Column not visible in the new library settings and library views

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, site-column

I have created a site column with field definition containing Hidden equals to true and added this site column to Document content type. Now I have created some content types which inherit Document content type and those content types used by libraries. Now I have a situation where I need to show that particular site column in library views.

So, to achieve this I am getting the field from the Document content type and set hidden to false and update the field.

By this, I am able to add the column in the library views, but the problem is that when I create new library this column is not visible to add it into a view.

```
Field field = clientContext.Web.GetContentTypeByName(contentType).Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(siteColumn);
field.Hidden = false;
field.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry(ConfigHelper.ThrottleRetryCount, ConfigHelper.ThrottleDelay);
```

and tried this as well

```
Field field = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(siteColumn);
field.Hidden = false;
field.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry(ConfigHelper.ThrottleRetryCount, ConfigHelper.ThrottleDelay);
```